# A Box contains 4 blue, 2 red and 3 black pens. If 3 pens are drawn at random (not replaced) ,whats the prob. of drawing 2 blue & 1 black pen?

Tags: probability

This seems to be a straightforward probability question but appears to have 2 contradicting answers :

Solution 1:
Probability of drawing 1 blue pen = 4/9
Probability of drawing another blue pen = 3/8
Probability of drawing 1 black pen = 3/7
Probability of drawing 2 blue pens and 1 black pen = 4/9 * 3/8 * 3/7 = 1/14

Reference (UnderDependent Event example 1) : https://www.mbacrystalball.com/blog/2015/07/03/probability/

Solution 2:
As there are 3 ways we can get the combination of 2 blue + 1 black - i.e ([Blue,Blue,Black],[Blue,Black,Blue],[Black,Blue,Blue]) it should be 3 times 1/14 (above answer).

Reference: https://www.quora.com/A-pack-contains-4-blue-2-red-and-3-black-pens-If-2-pens-are-drawn-at-random-from-the-pack-not-replaced-and-then-another-pen-is-drawn-What-is-the-probability-of-drawing-2-blue-pens-and-1-black-pen

Any idea on which is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is the correct one. The first one is the probability of having the first two draws blue and last draw black. That is different than having two blues and one black in total, i.e.

$$\begin{align}P(\text{2 blue and 1 black}) &= P(Blue, Blue, Black) + P(Blue, Black, Blue) \\&+ P(Black, Blue, Blue)\end{align}$$